# Changing the shade of color images. Example in thread. [Flash; as3]

Tags: flash

I try to do this with ColorTransform, but it changes the transparent pixels: http://savepic.su/2068100.png

Advise how to quickly change the hue of colors in the image and save the transparent pixels.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `ColorMatrixFilter` instead, which performs a matrix transform on each pixel's `[R, G, B, A]` vector.

For example, the following filter multiplies each pixel's red component by `1.2` and adds `25`. Each pixel's green component is multiplied by `0.8`.

```
var filter:* = new ColorMatrixFilter( [
    1.2, 0  , 0  , 0, 25,
    0  , 0.8, 0  , 0,  0,
    0  , 0  , 1  , 0,  0,
    0  , 0  , 0  , 1,  0
] );
```

If you want to do an actual *hue shift*, you'll have to construct a matrix that rotates the `[R, G, B]` 3D vector around the `[1, 1, 1]` vector. But I'm guessing that's more involved than what you're after.