# How to change orange color to green in bitmap using ColorMatrixFilter

Tags: java, image, colormatrixfilter

How to use the colorMatirxFilter to change orange color to green on a bitmap. Code samples would help. Please add explanation for the `ColorMatrixFilter` matrix.

I want to change the theme color based on user's selection.

Comment: If you do a hue shift, you'll change *all* colors in the image. Is that what you want? If you're using bitmaps, maybe you're better off copying the bitmap in-memory and replacing individual colors...

Comment: I want all orange pixels in the bitmap to change to green..

Comment: Replace all orange pixels manually. If you really want to use `ColorMatrixFilter`, see [my answer to another question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10863724/changing-the-shade-of-color-images-example-in-thread-flash-as3/10865680#10865680)

Comment: *"Code samples would help."* As would any sign of effort.  For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Answer (score 0):

As we know orange is not a pure color as Red, Green or Blue. 
This means that orange has three components, `R`,`G` and `B` components. Therefore, please try this:
1) Convert the orange (three values) to gray (one value) by using
   `Gray = 0.3*RED + 0.59*GREEN+0.11*Blue`;

2) Then, using `ColorMatrixFilter` (see Torious's link) set pixel values of those pixels which you want to change as:

Set `ZERO` (0 values) to Red and Blue components (as pixel values). 
Set the Gray value (we just calculated) to Green component (as pixel value).

Then, you get your result.